# Loading records in a grid dyamically (on request by the user)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am currently working on a PHP mysql application which has a grid with a few thousand records to display.Now,the requirement doesn't want it to be paginated in the normal way,(By displaying paging links **1,2,3** etc) but do it when user clicks on a link **Show More Results**. I have an anchor link,on click of which the next batch of records will be fetched from the server.The normal pagination as we all know can be achieved using the

```
     offset and limit parameters in a sql query
     select * from abc limit,offset;
```

So,in this case say my limit is "20",but how can make the calculations for the offset that will go to the query?
         I know basics of sending a ajax request on click.Something like this which would be called on click

```
     $.ajax({
       //request parameters and success and failure callback

     })
```

Any help or guidance on this would be very helpful.
Thanks for the time.

Comment: Have you considered Datatables? http://datatables.net/ It supports infinite scrolling and pagination (in case they change their mind about typical pagination). http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y_infinite.html

Comment: no I cannot use any customized plugins here.I have a html table/grid deigned as per requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey man i am giving you an idea only:

Consider You Have Table Links and Column Name Also Links in which there are links.

first use php directly in your html.

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
$("#more").click( function() {
var get = document.getElementsByClassName('num');
var numberofget = "limitnext="+get.length;
$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url : "more_results.php",
data : numberofget,
cache : false,
success : function(html){
$(this).remove();
$("#results").append(html);
}
});
});
});
</head>
<body>
<div id="results">
<?php

include("db.php");

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM Links LIMIT 0 , 20";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM Links";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1);
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result2);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
$links=$rows['links'];
echo "<div class='num'>".$links."</div>";
}

if($count>=20){
echo "<a id='more' href='#'>More Results of Links</a>";
}

?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**more_results.php**

```
<?php

include "db.php";

$limit=$_POST['limitnext'];
$limitaddup=$_POST['limitnext']+20;

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM Links LIMIT ".$limit." , ".$limitaddup.";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM Links";    
$result1 = mysql_query($query1);    
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result2);


while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){    
$links=$rows['links'];
echo "<div class='num'>".$links."</div>";
}


if($count>=$limitaddup){    
echo "<a id='more' href='#'>More Results of Links</a>";    
}    
?>
```

Comment: I will give it a try and revert if I have any issues!Thank you